# 'id' Parameter going into PreparedStatement as null

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, jstl

I have this method in a separate class,

```
  public void updateBook(String bookName, String bookAuthor,
            String bookGenres, String bookDesc, Date bookDueDate,
            String bookStatus, String fullname, int id) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,
                    username, password);

            String updateQuery = "UPDATE bookTrackerSystem SET bookname=?, bookAuthor=?, bookGenres=?, bookDesc=?, bookDueDate=?, fullname=? WHERE id=?";
            PreparedStatement update = connection.prepareStatement(updateQuery);

            update.setString(1, bookName);
            update.setString(2, bookAuthor);
            update.setString(3, bookGenres);
            update.setString(4, bookDesc);
            update.setDate(5, bookDueDate);
            update.setString(6, bookStatus);
            update.setString(7, fullname);

            update.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(update.toString());
            update.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And This JSP Page,

```
</head>
<%
    request.getParameter("id");
    session.setAttribute("id", request.getParameter("id"));
%>
<body>
    <div id="formDiv">

        <form action="UpdateBook" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Book Name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bookName"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Book Author:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bookAuthor"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Book Genre:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bookGenre"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Book Description:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bookDesc"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Book Due Date :</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bookDueDate"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Book Status:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bookStatus"></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit"
                        value="Update Book"></td>
                </tr>


            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

This servlet handles after the button is clicked

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String id_str = session.getAttribute("id").toString();

        BookTrackerBean sql = new BookTrackerBean();
        String bookName = request.getParameter("bookName");
        String bookAuthor = request.getParameter("bookAuthor");
        String bookGenres = request.getParameter("bookGenres");
        String bookDesc = request.getParameter("bookDesc");
        String bookDueDate = request.getParameter("bookDueDate");
        String bookStatus = request.getParameter("bookStatus");
        String fullname = request.getParameter("fullname");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(id_str);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(id);
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(bookDueDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

        sql.updateBook(bookName, bookAuthor, bookGenres, bookDesc, sqlDate,
                bookStatus, fullname, id);

    }
```

This all starts from grabbing the id from this page,

```
<body>
    <sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BookTracker" user="root" password="school" />

    <sql:query dataSource="${snapshot}" var="result">
SELECT * from BookTrackerSystem;
</sql:query>


    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Book ID</th>
            <th>Book Name</th>
            <th>Book Author</th>
            <th>Book Genre</th>
            <th>Book Description</th>
            <th>Book Due Date</th>
            <th>Book Status</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${row.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookName}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookAuthor}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookGenres}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookDesc}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookDueDate}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.bookStatus}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${row.fullname}" /></td>
                <td><a href="updatebook.jsp?id=${row.id}">Update</a></td>

            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</body>
```

Weird thing, I am encountering is, I can get & print 'id' perfectly but in the prepared statement it is going as null. Why?

Here's the PreparedStatement that executes when I click the button

```
UPDATE bookTrackerSystem SET bookname='aaaaaa', bookAuthor='', bookGenres='', bookDesc='', bookDueDate='1991-10-10', fullname='' WHERE id=null
```

Comment: In your update query `UPDATE bookTrackerSystem SET bookname=?, bookAuthor=?, bookGenres=?, bookDesc=?, bookDueDate=?, fullname=? WHERE id=?`, book status is missing. Add the book status in the query and try again.

Comment: Why did you remove the line `update.setInt(8, id);` from your above code ?

Comment: Smart ! You deleted the previous question where your PreparedStatement was wrong and now you post the same question with another wrong PreparedStatement .

Answer (score 0):

You are not submitting id back, take it in hidden field in form

Answer (score 0):

In your updateBook method,

```
update.setString(1, bookName);
            update.setString(2, bookAuthor);
            update.setString(3, bookGenres);
            update.setString(4, bookDesc);
            update.setDate(5, bookDueDate);
            update.setString(6, bookStatus);
            update.setString(7, fullname);
```

I don't see the code you are using to set the value of the Id, so this is the reason setting id as null,

if you add

update.setLong(8, id);

Comment: You mean you are not able to see this `update.setInt(8, id);` in the code posted in the question?

Comment: no this wont be right because you dont have any 8th position to put the 8th pramater.

Answer (score 0):

ID is not geting null. You are using wrong variable here.

```
update.setString(7, fullname);
```

7th position is for your where condition and you are placing fullname in that not id.

Change it to

```
update.setString(7, id);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `PreparedStatement` you need to pass the values in the same order as you need them in your query.

So for your statement `UPDATE bookTrackerSystem SET bookname=?, bookAuthor=?, bookGenres=?, bookDesc=?, bookDueDate=?, fullname=? WHERE id=?` you're passing wrong values for parameter 6 & 7 and you haven't added any parameter for id, which should be 8th parameter in your case.

So update your code according for 6th and 7th parameter and add id value as update.setString(8, id);